# Can this be changed to a convex problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

If I have a problem that is not convex
\begin{array}{lll}
\textbf{P1:} & \min_{\alpha,q} & \alpha q  \\
&\text{s.t} \quad &\alpha \leq 1    \\
&&\alpha \log_{2}\bigg(1+\dfrac{q}{\sigma^{2}}\bigg)\geq 5\\
&&\alpha \geq 0    \\
&&q \geq 0  
\end{array}
I think its noncovex because of the second constraint. I want to know how can I change such problems into convex. Any reference of book, slides, lectures, articles or name of a technique would be helpful. Also kindly name some techniques for nonconvex optimization like ant colony optimization etc. I would prefer if the reference is not of a book as I cannot buy books online and their is a fair chance that the hard copy of book will not be available in my county.

Comment: So $\alpha$ and $q$ are both scalars?  What does $(\alpha,q)$ mean in the objective function?

Comment: no they are not scalars, we a trying to fine the values of $\alpha$ and q that would optimize the system

Comment: Can you state explicitly what $\alpha$ and $q$ are?  Are they vectors in $\mathbb R^n$?  If so, what is the meaning of $\alpha \log_2(1 + q/\sigma^2)$?  In the objective function, is $(\alpha,q)$ the inner product of $\alpha$ and $q$?

Comment: sorry I wasn't able to understand your question before. yes they are both scalar, positive real numbers.

Comment: Ok, thanks, and can you clarify what function you're trying to minimize?  Since you only have two scalar unknowns, you could always just use a brute force search.

Comment: I am trying to minimize the product $\alpha$q , yes that's right I can brute force. But in this case its kind of compulsory for me to use a convex optimization technique.

Comment: I have edited the model for formatting, and to reflect your claim that your objective function is the product. If I've made an error, please let me know.

Comment: But no, your model is *not* convex. What do you mean by "compulsory" here? Surely someone is not expecting you to solve a non-convex problem using convex optimization. And this is a two-variable problem that can quite likely be solved analytically, or nearly so.

Comment: I'm going to change the $\varpropto$'s to $\alpha$'s, hope nobody objects.

Comment: I am supposed to solve this problem by changing it into a convex problem first( if possible). If the transformation is not possible then I am supposed to use some other techniques for nonconvex optimization. I wanted to know that is there a way to transform this into an equivalent convex problem.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.

Comment: An excellent reference is [this book](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) by Boyd and Vandenberghe.

Comment: Boyd and Vandenberghe is not going to help you determine how to transform this problem to a convex form. In fact, such a transformation is _rarely_ possible; and if it is, only through a change of variables... which I see is exactly what @LinAlg has done

Comment: @MichaelGrant The book at least equips you with in-depth knowledge on convexity. There are in fact many more tricks. I once had a seminar from Ben-Tal at MIT where he showed many of those. If you search for 'hidden convexity' you can find a few of them.

Comment: Great pointer, @LinAlg, thank you, I will check itout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please forget about ant colony optimization. Its a heuristic with unpredictable performance.

Making problems convex is an ad-hoc procedure that requires practice.

The objective is the first hurdle here. It is indefinite. A logarithmic transformation gets rid of the product, but results in a concave minimization problem. We can make the objective linear again with the substitution $x=\exp(\alpha)$ and $y=\exp(q)$. Let's see what happens to the constraint:
$$\log(x) \log(1+\log(y)/\sigma^2) \geq 5$$
$$\log((1+\log(y)/\sigma^2)^{\log(x)}) \geq 5$$
$$(1+\log(y)/\sigma^2)^{\log(x)} \geq \exp(5)$$
$$1+\log(y)/\sigma^2 \geq \exp(5)^{1/\log(x)}$$
Here I used that $\log(x)\geq 0$. The final constraint is convex as $x \geq 1$. Finding an initial feasible point is slightly harder since the constraints are not convex outside the feasible region, but for this two variable problem that is not a real issue. The final problem becomes:
$$\begin{align*}
\min \quad  &x+y \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & x \leq e \\
& 1+\frac{\log(y)}{\sigma^2} \geq \exp(5)^{1/\log(x)} \\
& x,y \geq 1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Feel free to replace $\exp$ with $2^{(\cdot)}$ and $\log$ with $\log_2$ throughout.